# getMessage() on Exception object does not provides null

Tags: java, exception, null, getmessage

With a code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Exception one = new Exception("my cause");
    System.out.println("A) " + one.getMessage());

    System.out.println();

    Exception two = new Exception(one);
    System.out.println("B) " + two.getMessage());
    System.out.println("C) " + two.getCause().getMessage());

    System.out.println();

    Exception three = new Exception("my message", one);
    System.out.println("D) " + three.getMessage());
    System.out.println("E) " + three.getCause().getMessage());

    System.out.println();

    Exception fourth = new Exception(null, one);
    System.out.println("F) " + fourth.getMessage());
    System.out.println("G) " + fourth.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

The output is this one

```
A) my cause

B) java.lang.Exception: my cause
C) my cause

D) my message
E) my cause

F) null
G) my cause
```

See the difference between `B` and `F`

In both cases I did NOT provided a message, but the difference is that in the `B` case the `null` value is not forced.

It seems that for the `B` case, when a message is not specified, the `getMessage()` method provides the format
`className: cause.getMessage()`
But I would except to have a `null` value (as is for the `F` case).

Is there a way to get `null` value (like `F`) if I call the `getMessage` on an Exception that has been created providing only the `cause` and not the `message`?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`Exception`'s JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.Throwable)). For the constructor that takes only a `Throwable`:

> Constructs a new exception with the specified cause and a detail message of `(cause==null ? null : cause.toString())` (which typically contains the class and detail message of `cause`). This constructor is useful for exceptions that are little more than wrappers for other throwables (for example, `PrivilegedActionException`).

So, in your B case, since the cause is not null, you get the value of `cause.toString()` as the container exception's message.

If that constructor was used to create the exception, then by the time you catch the exception, it's too late - it already has a detail message as specified above. You can't get the "null" as the detail message is not null. You can compare it to the cause's `toString()` and deduce that it should have been null, but that's a kludge and theoretically, the cause's message could change over time and be different at the time of the catch.

Comment: I edited the main message with a simple method that handle this behaviour. It may not be the best approach but for my case works just fine.

Comment: Oh ok, I always edited the main question with the proper solution (making clear that was an edit from the first question). I added the reply as a different one. Hope is better now

Answer (score 0):

Basing on @RealSkeptic reply I created a method like this

```
public static String getMessageOrNull(Throwable t) {
    String message = t.getMessage();

    if (t.getCause() != null && message.equals(t.getCause().toString())) {
        message = null;
    }

    return message;
}
```

It may not be the best approach but for my case works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply build it the same way, hiding it in a static method :

```
public static Exception getException(Throwable cause){
    return new Exception(null, cause);
}
```

Or you define your own class that will use the `Exception(String, Throwable)` constructor like

```
public MyExceptoin extends Exception{

    public MyException(Throwable cause){
        super(null, cause);
    }
}
```

This would be simpler to use later.